# How do I install Wordpress in a subdirectory and it successfully loads?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website already installed in the root folder.

However I created a subfolder called "weddings" and installed another wordpress site into that subfolder successfully.

The problem is whenever I try to load up the subfolder wordpress site, it doesn't show the new site, it only shows the primary wordpress site.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried pointing the domain to subfolder?

Comment: You need to add an .htaccess rule, otherwise your main WP site will always attempt to show anything in the subfolder as part of itself: https://serverfault.com/questions/956060/htaccess-nested-wordpress-folder-redirect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes it can work fine but only change .htacess file path

Comment: example please? do i edit the .htaccess in the root directory or the sub directory?

Comment: This answer lacks detail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).